# Group function is nested too deeply SQL Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which looks like this:

```
+-----------------+--------------+
| Field           | Type         |
+-----------------+--------------+
| orderNumber (PK)| int          |
| orderDate       | date         |
| requiredDate    | date         |
| shippedDate     | date         |
| status          | char(15)     |
| comments        | char(200)    |
| customerNumber  | int          |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

I need to return the customerNumber which has maximum number of orders.

I tried the following command:

```
SELECT customerNumber FROM ORDERS WHERE customerNumber IN (SELECT customerNumber FROM ORDERS HAVING MAX(COUNT(customerNumber)) GROUP BY customerNumber);
```

I think an error: group function is nested too deeply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03b88/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
  orderNumber     int PRIMARY KEY,
  orderDate       date,
  requiredDate    date,
  shippedDate     date,
  status          char(15),
  comments        char(200),
  customerNumber  int
);

INSERT INTO ORDERS ( ORDERNUMBER, CUSTOMERNUMBER ) VALUES ( 1, 1 );
INSERT INTO ORDERS ( ORDERNUMBER, CUSTOMERNUMBER ) VALUES ( 2, 1 );
INSERT INTO ORDERS ( ORDERNUMBER, CUSTOMERNUMBER ) VALUES ( 3, 2 );
INSERT INTO ORDERS ( ORDERNUMBER, CUSTOMERNUMBER ) VALUES ( 4, 2 );
INSERT INTO ORDERS ( ORDERNUMBER, CUSTOMERNUMBER ) VALUES ( 5, 3 );
INSERT INTO ORDERS ( ORDERNUMBER, CUSTOMERNUMBER ) VALUES ( 6, 4 );
```

**Query 1 - If you only want to get a single customer**:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERNUMBER
FROM   (
  SELECT CUSTOMERNUMBER,
         COUNT( ORDERNUMBER ) AS num_orders
  FROM   ORDERS
  GROUP BY CUSTOMERNUMBER
  ORDER BY num_orders DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03b88/2/0)**:

```
| CUSTOMERNUMBER |
|----------------|
|              1 |
```

**Query 2 - If you want to get all customers with the highest number of orders**:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERNUMBER
FROM (
  SELECT CUSTOMERNUMBER,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY NUM_ORDERS DESC ) AS RNK
  FROM   (
    SELECT CUSTOMERNUMBER,
           COUNT( ORDERNUMBER ) AS num_orders
    FROM   ORDERS
    GROUP BY CUSTOMERNUMBER
    ORDER BY num_orders DESC
  )
)
WHERE RNK = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03b88/2/1)**:

```
| CUSTOMERNUMBER |
|----------------|
|              1 |
|              2 |
```

Comment: what if there are multiple rows with equal value?

Comment: @user1692342 The question does not specify that multiple rows are required - however, I've updated with a second solution that will return multiple rows which are highest ranked in number of orders (and does not require any self-joins).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using `cte`s, where you get the count of orders in the first cte, then select the maximum value. Finally join them to get the customer with the maximum orders.

```
with ordercount as (select customernumber, count(distinct ordernumber) ordercount
                   from orders 
                   group by customernumber)
,maxorders as (select max(ordercount) maxcount from ordercount)
select o.customernumber
from ordercount o 
join maxorders m on m.maxcount = o.ordercount
```